# insert into vtiger table, php

Tags: php, vtiger

I have code which connecting to vtiger and now i have problem to insert data into vtiger module Accounts. With select statement I haven't problem, it's working fine, but i cannot insert data. I want to create new organization.

```
function call($url, $params, $type = "GET")
{
    $is_post = 0;
    if($type == "POST") {
        $is_post = 1;
        $post_data = $params;
    } else {
        $url = $url . "?" . http_build_query($params);
    }
    $ch = curl_init($url);
    if(!$ch) {
        die("Cannot allocate a new PHP-CURL handle");
    }
    if($is_post) {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, $is_post);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($params));
    }

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);

    $return = null;
    if(curl_error($ch)) {
        $return = false;
    } else {
        $return = json_decode($data, true);
    }

    curl_close($ch);

    return $return;
}

$endpointUrl = 'http://localhost/vtigercrm/webservice.php';
$userName = 'username';
$password = 'pass';
$userAccessKey = 'acckey';

$sessionData = call($endpointUrl, array(
    "operation" => "getchallenge",
    "username" => $userName
));
$challengeToken = $sessionData['result']['token'];
$generatedKey = md5($challengeToken . $userAccessKey);
$dataDetails = call($endpointUrl, array(
    "operation" => "login",
    "username" => $userName,
    "accessKey" => $generatedKey
), "POST");
$query = "INSERT INTO Accounts(accountname) VALUES ('some_name');";
$sessionid = $dataDetails['result']['sessionName'];
$getUserDetail = call($endpointUrl, array(
    "operation" => "query",
    "sessionName" => $sessionid,
    'query' => $query
));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

To create an object with the webservice you should use the "create" operation not "query"

You can check the webservice tutorial :

https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/Webservices_tutorials#Create

Comment: I have try with create but still haven't success.                           
         $updateTable = call($endpointUrl, array("operation" => "create", "sessionName" => $sessionid, "element" => "URLENCODED(" . $query . ")", "elementType" => "Accounts"), "POST");